# What does Cats Effect's IO.suspend function really do?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

What does cats-effect's `IO.suspend` do and why it is useful? There's documentation, but it isn't completely clear.

The [documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#deferred-execution--iosuspend) gives the following use case:

```scala
import cats.effect.IO

def fib(n: Int, a: Long, b: Long): IO[Long] =
  IO.suspend {
    if (n > 0)
      fib(n - 1, b, a + b)
    else
      IO.pure(a)
  }
```

As an example, why would I want to use the above, vs. the following similar function?

```scala
import cats.effect.IO

import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def fib(n: Int, a: Long, b: Long): IO[Long] =
  if (n > 0)
    fib(n -1, b, a + b)
  else
    IO.pure(a)
```

Comment: In your second code, the `if (n > 0)` branch is eagerly evaluated, this is exactly what you wanted to stop (as this branch is all computation goes into) . The other branch is very light. So, in your second code, `IO` is being used for purely cosmetic purposes and you could have as well not used it at all.

Comment: As for `why suspension is useful ?`, that revolves around the fundamental paradigm of being able to represent `"process"` as `data`, so that you can analyse it to figure out better optimzations, pruning of unnacessary branches and so on. And then you finally run your pruned and optimized `"process"` instead of the one which was `"written"`. Another reason is to mantain referential transparency which is fundamental to functional programming and mathematical reasoning in general.

Comment: Also, remember we are converting your `"process"` into `data` which means that you are lifting your process from being nested funcation calls to being a nested data structure... which again means that we are free from all worries about stack safety. As you might recall, not all recursive computations can be made tail recusrive (or require some convoluted logic change or require use of things like continuations), this approach allows us to use non-tail-recusrive implementations with stack safety (because we are not using stack for recursion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of them is lazy, the other is eager.

```
def printFibIfNeeded(n: Int, shouldPrint: Boolean) = {
  val fibResult = fib(n, 0, 1)
  if (shouldPrint) fibResult.map(r => println(r))
  else IO.unit
}
```

If you use `suspend`, then `fibResult` will be just a recipe for computation that won't be run if `shouldPrint. = false`.

In your second example you already computer the value and just wrapped it with IO, so you made your computer run CPU even though it eventually wasn't necessary.

With pure computations it might look like an optimization, but what if you had side effects there?

```
def dropAllUsersInDB: Future[Unit]

def eagerDrop = IO.fromFuture(IO.pure(dropAllUsersInDB))

def lazyDrop = IO.fromFuture(IO.suspend(IO.pure(dropAllUsersInDB)))
```

The first example creates `Future` which would drop all users - so whether or not we compose this IO into our program Users are being deleted.

The second example have `suspend` somewhere in the IO recipe so this `Future` is NOT created unless IO will be evaluated. So Users are safe unless we explicitly compose this IO into something that will become a part of the computation.

In your example this will become more visible if you do:

```
def fib(n: Int, a: Long, b: Long): IO[Long] =
  IO.suspend {
    println("evaluating")
    if (n > 0)
      fib(n - 1, b, a + b)
    else
      IO.pure(a)
  }
```

and

```
@tailrec
def fib(n: Int, a: Long, b: Long): IO[Long] = {
  println("evaluating")
  if (n > 0)
    fib(n -1, b, a + b)
  else
    IO.pure(a)
}
```

Then call `fib` to create an IO value without evaluating it, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: lazy/eager is the "how". 

The main question is "why". So why lazy: because it allows suspending side effects. 

And why suspending side effects? That's the essence of FP!

Because when reasoning about a pure function you don't care about the history of its executions. Executing it once or many times it will always do the same exact thing. 

Which is NOT true in impure functions, and all side effects lead to such impure functions. Lazy is just a mechanism to avoid all that trouble.